# how to use scala internals to compile source faster than fsc (fast scala compiler)

Tags: scala, tdd, performance

fsc (fast scala compiler) is faster than scalac. but during TDD cycles i consume 3 seconds to compile sources over less than 1s to run my tests.. suggestion to reduce compile time near 0?

obviously, buy a faster computer is not an answer :)

i mean use some scala internals to compile source faster as possible

Answer (score 6):

http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/

Comment: SBT can be configured to compile and run tests every time you save the source files. `> ~test`

Answer (score 3):

Just go with [SBT](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/). But, if you are using Scala 2.8, these links might help as well:

- [Dependency-aware Maven Builds](http://blogtrader.net/blog/how_to_setup_dependencies_aware2)
- [Dependency-aware ANT Builds](http://blogtrader.net/blog/how_to_setup_dependencies_aware)